# Controlling lights by XBee S1+ ESP32 without bridge

Tags: c++, esp32, xbee

I need some help with my ideas please, I have a smart home system and I am trying to control the Philips hue light but without the bridge.
I want to do that by XBee S1 + FURTHER ESP 32.
so, who did that or have any ideas about how that can possible.
Any links, Videos, tutorials will be greater.
thanks all.

Comment: do Phillips Hue lights use XBee modules for communication?

Comment: For Now, I am using the bridge but I want to control them XBee to turn it off/on. the system is not in my home I am working on it.  so what I want to do turn off the bridge and control the lights from the XBee ,    as I saw from the internet I can do that with the transport key of the light + XCTU software +xbee S1. but I am lost I don't know how to start.